# I'm using bash on Debian 11. But how may I open a Bourne, Korn or C-Shell if I am willing to?

Tags: bash, debian, ksh, csh

I am reading a book speaking about *Bourne Shell* (the ancestor of `bash` = *Bourne-Again Shell* I'm currently using), *Korn Shell* and *C-Shell*.

I was curious, and willing to experience them.

On a `bash` terminal under *Debian 11* I've attempted to execute:

```bash
bsh
ksh
csh
```

but without success.

How shall I do that?

Comment: They are not installed by default. I assume you have installed packages before on Debian and know how to search for a command. I've not got a clue what `bsh` is.

Comment: On Debian, I think `dash` is the closest you get to Bourne shell.

Comment: @glennjackman, no, `dash` intends to be a POSIX shell, so not compatible with the Bourne shell. The Bourne shell was non-free software and is no longer used these days. Since the source code was released as part of OpenSolaris a few years ago, there have been several attempts to port it to Linux including http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html and http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html if you're interested in archeology. @Schily even extended and modified it to make it POSIX compatible in his bosh shell.

Comment: If this is an exercise in computer archaeology, you should be able to run Unix version 7 from the late 70s where the Bourne shell was first released in some PDP11 emulator like `simh`. Same for 2BSD for the original csh. You'll likely find some images that include ksh88. ksh88 can be found on Solaris which is now available for amd64 and should run in a VM on your Debian (both qemu/kvm and virtualbox)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I always appreciate your thorough historical perspective!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csh` and `ksh` are available in the eponymous packages:

```
sudo apt install csh ksh
```

Depending on the vintage of the book you’re reading, and the shells it’s based on, you might find differences in behaviour with the versions of `csh` and `ksh` currently available in Debian.

The Bourne shell isn’t available directly, but `dash` (which is installed by default on Debian) is a descendant of the Almquist shell, which was written as a clone of the Bourne shell. `dash` has been made POSIX-compliant however, which means it’s no longer compatible with the Bourne shell.

Outside of Debian, you can find an updated version of [the Bourne shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) in [the Heirloom Project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: dash is a descendant of ash, a clone of the Bourne shell with some modifications. However dash was made POSIX compliant, so is no longer compatible with the Bourne shell. See my comment to the question for more info.

Comment: Note the the `ksh` package on Debian is based on ksh93, a (often considered "experimental") rewrite of the Korn shell by David Korn and co. It's not fully backward compatible with ksh88, the original ksh based on the Bourne shell. AFAIK, ksh88 source code was never released as opensource, though you can find the source code of some versions on archive.org at least. I don't know if anyone ever attempted to port it to Linux.

Answer (score -3):

Type:
`which zsh ksh csh`
if that show nothing in the output then run
`sudo apt install zsh ksh csh -y` and then run the
`which zsh ksh csh` again. It will show you them as installed now.

```
cloud_user@b12674a8e11c:~$ which zsh csh ksh
/usr/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/csh
/usr/bin/ksh
```

Then type `zsh`
This'll bring you into your new shell environment.
Additional note, type

```
echo $0
```

to verify which shell you are using. You can always `exit` the 'zsh' shell and go back to your prior shell.

Comment: You might also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at the the [code of conduct](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) for abusive language.

Comment: Note that `echo $0` won't work in csh when started interactively, at least with the csh from the csh package on Debian (based on openbsd's csh)